# User should be signed-out from application if user session is expired on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-state

I am working on Asp.net MVC 3 application in which I have a method of logout in Account Controller.

```
 public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            try
            {
               // Session.User = null;

                this._authenticationService.SignOut();

                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

I want to call this method from Session_End Method in global.asax.cs or Is there any other way to call `RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");` from global.asax.cs file.

Comment: Are you attempting to do something outside of user's request? (Also note that [Session_End is not fired for SQL/state service session state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852942/how-do-you-programatically-end-a-session-in-asp-net) ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Ajax+JavaScript based solution, just check similar thread which would help you:

[Client-side session timeout redirect in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852121/client-side-session-timeout-redirect-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Session_End()
    {
        // Clear the error on server. 
        Server.ClearError(); 
        Response.Clear(); 

        RouteData routeData = new RouteData(); 

        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Account"); 
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Login"); 


        // Call target Controller and pass the routeData. 
        IController AccountMainController = new AccountController(); 
        AccountMainController.Execute(new RequestContext( 
                new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
    }
```

Comment: At Response.Clear() line my debugger control goes out from application and next line didnot execute.

Comment: Can you remove that line and give a try

Comment: On var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData); same thing is happening...

Comment: new HttpContextWrapper(Context) threw an exception of ArgumentNullException

Comment: new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), HttpContext.Current is also null

Answer (score 0):

"Session_End" does not correspond to any request or in any request flow, so redirecting/executing controller actions will not return HTML to browser. As long as the browser makes requests to server, hardly there will be a chance to get the "Session_End" executed. Probably you can use an object stored in session and when session ends the object will be abandoned from session store.

Writing a common code in Begin_Request event or Global Filter in MVC can check for the presence of that object and can redirect the user to log off action if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are able to use signalr in your current project, but if you are, you can use signalr to call the redirect on the client side if the session expired.

Something like that on the serverside:

```
protected void Session_End()
{
    GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ConnectionStateHub>().Clients[{yourClientsId}].SessionExpired({yourRedirectTarget});
}
```

On the client side, something like the following could make the redirect:

```
var sessionHub = $.connection.sessionHub;
sessionHub.sessionExpired = function(target) { window.location = target; }
```